# Apache Commons Imaging .jar from project

Tags: android, apache, imaging

I am using Android studio and want to use org.apache.commons.imaging library for the project.

For this I am not getting .jar file to add to library but I am getting the apache project file at:- https://github.com/apache/commons-imaging

How to use this zip file (availale at above link) to make or get .jar file

Answer (score 0):

The project was recently renamed from sanselan and as they say have not yet released a stable version.

You can however download a jar of the project from before the renaming here:
[Download sanselan](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/download_sanselan.cgi)

Or just add

```
compile 'org.apache.sanselan:sanselan:0.97-incubator'
```

To your list of dependencies